# Drag and drop folder as input for a Mac command file

Tags: bash, shell, automator

I created a small script to convert music files and saved it to a `converter.command` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

srcDir=/path/to/folder
for i in "$srcDir"/*.{wac,aiff,aif}; do 
    ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.flac"
done
```

I would like to be able to drag and drop my folder onto the command which would take as `srcDir` the path of that folder.

I think I have to look automator, which I did, but I'm not sure how to achieve it.

Comment: Try `srcdir=$1`; if that works; probably refactor to handle both individual files and directories in `"$@"`

Comment: When I double click on the file, $1 does not change anything. I'm not asked to enter anything

Comment: You asked how to get it to process a folder you drag onto it.

Comment: I canot drag a folder on a .command file. I tried to create an app with automator but it gives nothing